# read file in classpath

Tags: java, spring, file-io, classpath

Here is what I want to do and I am wondering if there is any Spring classes that will help with implementing.  I don't have to use spring for this particular problem, I'm just implementing it with everything else.

In my DAO layer I want to externalize my sql files aka 1 sql per file. I want to read and cache the sql statement even maybe as a spring bean singleton. But in my initial struggles, I am having a problem just loading a sql file in the classpath...

Is there anything in spring to help with that? I've been through the documentation but nothing is jumping out at me.

Here is kind of what I'm after.. but I can't get it to recognize the file or maybe the classpath... not real sure does something need to be defined in applicationContext?

Here are a couple of attempts that do not seem to work... both spring'ish and just java'ish.

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ClassPathResource("com.company.app.dao.sql.SqlQueryFile.sql").getInputStream())

reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("com.company.app.dao.sql.SqlQueryFile.sql")));
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try getting Spring to inject it, assuming you're using Spring as a dependency-injection framework.

In your class, do something like this:

```
public void setSqlResource(Resource sqlResource) {
    this.sqlResource = sqlResource;
}
```

And then in your application context file, in the bean definition, just set a property:

```
<bean id="someBean" class="...">
    <property name="sqlResource" value="classpath:com/somecompany/sql/sql.txt" />
</bean>
```

And Spring should be clever enough to load up the file from the classpath and give it to your bean as a resource.

You could also look into [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html), and store all your SQL in property files and just inject each one separately where needed. There are lots of options.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was after.  I'm fairly new to spring and this seems to work nicely.  Unfortunately I had this same question posted on the spring forum and got no responses... +1 to stackoverfow.

Comment: Good answer! Is that Resource org.springframework.core.io.Resource?

Answer (score 39):

Change . to / as the path separator and use `getResourceAsStream`:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
        "com/company/app/dao/sql/SqlQueryFile.sql")));
```

or

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    getClass().getResourceAsStream(
        "/com/company/app/dao/sql/SqlQueryFile.sql")));
```

Note the leading slash when using `Class.getResourceAsStream()` vs `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`.
`getSystemResourceAsStream` uses the *system* classloader which isn't what you want.

I suspect that using slashes instead of dots would work for `ClassPathResource` too.

Comment: Be careful of the leading /. If the above code is accessed from a class in package com.company.app.dao.sql, you really just want SqlQueryFile.sql there. If the code is accessed from another package, you need a leading /

Comment: oh wait a sec - you really want getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() - it's non-static

Comment: I did notice you needed the getClass() but for some reason it didn't work.  I'm sure it is really close though.  It looks like it should work.  The Spring answer I received is what I'm after so I'm not going to pursue this one anymore.  Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Okay, will edit this to use getClass().getClassLoader() for posterity though.

Comment: Okay, I know this is old, but it's gelled. You'll need to use (ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()) or <MyClassName>.class.getResourceAsStream(). It baffles me why someone pointed to this answer to clarify another answer when it *would not compile*.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class readFile {
    /**
     * feel free to make any modification I have have been here so I feel you
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        File dir = new File(".");// read file from same directory as source //
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                // if you wanna read file name with txt files
                if (file.getName().contains("txt")) {
                    System.out.println(file.getName());
                }

                // if you want to open text file and read each line then
                if (file.getName().contains("txt")) {
                    try {
                        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
                        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(
                                file.getAbsolutePath());
                        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                fileReader);
                        String line;
                        // get file details and get info you need.
                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            // here you can say...
                            // System.out.println(line.substring(0, 10)); this
                            // prints from 0 to 10 indext
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Unable to open file '"
                                + file.getName() + "'");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Error reading file '"
                                + file.getName() + "'");
                        // Or we could just do this:
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }`enter code here`

}
```