# reading from a file with Maven

Tags: maven, package, filenotfoundexception, filereader

I am trying to build a very little program with MAVEN that reads from a file but I obviosly do something wrong because it gives me FileNotFoundException.

This is how my directory structure looks like:

```
my-app
      src
         main|
             |
             |--java|
             |      |
             |      Main.java
             |
             |--resources|
                         |
                         res.txt
```

The res.txt contains some Strings that I'd like to read from Main.java

```
...
File file = new File("res.txt");
FileReader fr= new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( fr);
...
```

I compile it with : 
C:\my-app  mvn package

It creates the jar under target. When I peep inside the jar, I see it contains both Main.class and res.text *next to each other*.(under the same directory)

Still, when I try to run it :
java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Main

I gives my FileNotFoundException, Main.class somehow does not see res.txt file. Why? Where should I put res.txt? What else should I configure?

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the .txt file is copied to the target folder and part of the jar file?

In that case use a resource loader to retrieve it from the classpath and not from the file-system.

see [read file in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734671/read-file-in-classpath) for some examples how to load files.

Comment: when I peep into the jar I see this:
----META-INF(directory)
----Main.class
----res.text

Comment: thats perfect. You should be able to read the file from the classpath.

Comment: like this?
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("res.txt")));

Comment: Sadly thats the result:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: anyway as I had more chance to play with it I found that the question is more classpath related than maven related. If I unpack the jar and run the class from the aprropriate place than it DOES find the res.text But if I try to run it outside of the jar like this: java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Main than it DOES NOT find the textfile. So the problem must be classpath related I beleive

Answer (score 0):

You may try with

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/res.txt").getFile());
```

or even

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/res.txt").toURI());
```

Comment: anyway as I had more chance to play with it I found that the question is more classpath related than maven related. If I unpack the jar and run the class from the aprropriate place than it DOES find the res.text But if I try to run it outside of the jar like this: java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Main than it DOES NOT find the textfile. So the problem must be classpath related I beleive

Answer (score 0):

InputStream TokenStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/files/Token.xlsx");

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(TokenStream);

XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

This works for reading excel file